# Detecting subscript in command argument

Tags: macros, conditionals, subscripts, ifthenelse, xifthen

I have defined a command `low` that adds a subscript to an argument:

```
\newcommand{\low}[1]{{#1}_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}}
```

However, if the argument of `low` contains subscripts itsself (for example in the case of `\low{\low{\Sigma}}`) it is not easy to see that the subscripts introduced by the outer `low` belong to the whole argument and not just to the first subscript. Therefore I would like to automatically introduce parentheses if the argument of `low` contains a subscript (so `\low{\low{\Sigma}}` should look like `\low{(\low{\Sigma})}`.

In order to achieve this I tried the following using the xifthen package:

```
\newcommand{\low}[1]{\ifthenelse{\isin{_}{#1}}{{(#1)}_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}}{{#1}_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}}}
```

However to my surprise this command only sometimes inserts the parantheses.
In particular it does not do so in the example given above. Why does this happen and what can I do to fix this?

EDIT: It seems that the problem is that `\isin` does not unroll the definitions of commands. @egreg has already provided an answer that allows me to check for nested calls of `\low` but does not work for arguments that contain other commands with subscripts. Does anyone have a solution that works for arbitrary arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In some cases applying `\protected@edef` and `\@onelevel@sanitize` before checking for a "stringified" `_` might work out:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xifthen}

\makeatletter    
\DeclareRobustCommand\DetectUnderscore[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \@onelevel@sanitize\@tempa
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\ifthenelse
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\isin
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\string_%
  \expandafter}%
  \expandafter{%
  \@tempa}}{{(#1)}}{{#1}}%
}%
\newcommand\low[1]{%
  \DetectUnderscore{#1}%
  _{l_{\mathcal{A}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
\low{\Sigma} \qquad 
\low{\low{\Sigma}} \qquad
\low{\low{\low{\Sigma}}} \qquad
\]
\[
\low{\Sigma_b} \qquad 
\low{\low{\Sigma_b}} \qquad
\low{\low{\low{\Sigma_b}}} \qquad
\]
\[
\low{{\Sigma_b}} \qquad
\low{b_{\low{c_{\low{\Sigma_d}}}}} \qquad
(\Sigma_b)_{l_\mathcal{A}}
\]
\[
\low{\low{1} + 2}
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\expandafter` causes that the next but one token —if expandable—gets expanded exactly once  before the next token gets expanded if expandable. (La)TeX considers the work of `\expandafter` done when expansion of the next but one token is done. Therefore you can use chains/sequences of `\expandafter` to have (La)TeX "jump" over k tokens for first expanding the (k+1)-th token.

`\@onelevel@sanitize\macro` changes the definition of `\macro` so that `\macro` spits out a sequence of character tokens of category code 12(other) that looks like the token-sequence that would have been "spit out" by `\macro` before applying `\@onelevel@sanitize`. It is almost like redefining `\macro` to what you get by applying `\string` to each token of `\macro`'s definition.

`\protected@edef` defines a macro but before doing so, it expands all expandable tokens of the definition-text except those that either are defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand` or are preceded by the token `\protect`. You might say: `\protected@edef` does "unroll" the definitions of the tokens contained in its definition-text before actually performing the assignment.

`\@tempa` is a scratch-macro which gets defined by means of `\protected@edef` to expand to the argument `#1` with all definitions in `#1` "unrolled".

The `\ifthenelse{\isin...}`-test does not find `_` that are nested in curly-braces as curly braces usually have a special function. Therefore `\@onelevel@sanitize` is applied for turning all tokens, and thus also the curly braces, into ordinary harmless character-tokens of category code 12(other) which do not disturb the `\ifthenelse{\isin...}` test.

---

And here is a routine which does not check for (stringified) underscore of category code 12 (other) via **xifthen**'s `\ifthenelse{\isin...}`-thingie but does check for tokens of category code 8 (subscript) without stringification.

The routine recursively calls itself when examining the tokens that form the argument.

The routine still does not expand the argument—this still has to be done via `\protected@edef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Paraphernalia ;-) :
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@exchange[2]{#2#1}%
\newcommand\UD@removespace{}\UD@firstoftwo{\def\UD@removespace}{} {}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Extract first inner undelimited argument:
%%.............................................................................
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{ABCDE} yields  {A}
%%
%%   \UD@ExtractFirstArg{{AB}CDE} yields  {AB}
%%
%% !!! The argument of \UD@ExtractFirstArg must not be empty. !!!
%% You can check for emptiness via \UD@CheckWhetherNull before applying
%% \UD@ExtractFirstArg.
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#1\UD@SelDOm}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%.............................................................................
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument's first token is a catcode-1-character
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked has no leading
%%                        catcode-1-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBrace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{%
  \string#1.}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@firstoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a space-token
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is a
%%                               space-token>}%
%%                             {<Tokens to be delivered in case <argument
%%                               which is to be checked>'s 1st token is not
%%                               a space-token>}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}%
  {\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@secondoftwo}%
  {\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB.#1 }{}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB{}%
\long\def\UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpaceB#1 {%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@secondoftwo#1{}}%
  {\UD@exchange{\UD@firstoftwo}}{\UD@exchange{\UD@secondoftwo}}%
  {\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\expandafter\expandafter
   \expandafter}\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\string}%
}%
%%.............................................................................
%% Check whether brace-balanced argument starts with a token of
%% category code 8 (subscript)
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherFirstTokenHasCatcodeSubscript{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that 
%%                         <argument which is to be checked> has a first
%%                         token of catcode 8>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                         <argument which is to be checked> does not have
%%                         a first token of catcode 8>}%
%%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherFirstTokenHasCatcodeSubscript[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter}\UD@secondoftwo}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter}\UD@secondoftwo}{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter}\UD@secondoftwo}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherFirstTokenHasCatcodeSubscript
        \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherFirstTokenHasCatcodeSubscript[1]{%
  \expandafter\ifcat_#1%
  \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\fi
  {\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter}\UD@firstoftwo}%
  {\UD@exchange{ }{\expandafter}\UD@secondoftwo}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument does contain underscore/tokens of 
%% category code 8 (subscript), no matter if nested in braces or not.
%%
%% \UD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that 
%%                     <argument which is to be checked> contains
%%                     some token(s) of catcode 8 (subscript)>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                     <argument which is to be checked> contains
%%                     no token of catcode 8 (subscript)>}%
%%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens{\romannumeral0\UD@@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens}%
\newcommand\UD@@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens[3]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ #3}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherLeadingSpace{#1}{%
      \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens\expandafter{\UD@removespace#1}{#2}{#3}%
    }{%
      \UD@CheckWhetherBrace{#1}{%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens
        \UD@ExtractFirstArg{#1}{ #2}{%
          \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
        }%
      }{%
        \UD@CheckWhetherFirstTokenHasCatcodeSubscript{#1}{ #2}{%
           \expandafter\UD@@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}{#3}%
        }%
      }%
    }%
  }%
}%

\DeclareRobustCommand\UD@CallUD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokensOnExpansion[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokens\expandafter{\@tempa}{{(#1)}}{{#1}}%
}%

\newcommand\low[1]{%
  \UD@CallUD@CheckWhetherSubscriptTokensOnExpansion{#1}_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% Let`s use | and \myunderscore in the same way as _ :

\catcode`\|=8

\let\myunderscore=_

\[
\low{\Sigma} \qquad 
\low{\low{\Sigma}} \qquad
\low{\low{\low{\Sigma}}} \qquad
\]
\[
\low{\Sigma\myunderscore b} \qquad 
\low{\low{\Sigma\myunderscore b}} \qquad
\low{\low{\low{\Sigma|b}}} \qquad
\]
\[
\low{{\Sigma_b}} \qquad
\low{b_{\low{c_{\low{\Sigma|d}}}}} \qquad
(\Sigma_b)_{l_\mathcal{A}}
\]
\[
\low{\low{1} + 2}
\]    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that this routine does not aim at detecting (stringified) `_`-character-tokens of category-code 12 (other) but at detecting all character-tokens (be they explicit or implicit) of category code 8 (subscript).

Comment: For the sake of having fun I just added another routine which required a bit more of -eh- crocheting and knitting by hand. ;-) That routine takes into account that you might use `_` with a different catcode for other purposes than math-subscripting, and it also takes into account that you may assign catcode 8 to characters other than `_` for using them for math-subscripting...

Answer (score 1):

An idea (not straight forward solution) is to place the argument inside a box and check its height with the height of a character you suppose is not too tall to need parenthesis but not too short to add parenthesis to your \Sigma.

And guess what will be our default argument: `\Sigma`... P

The code (containing some tests) is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\DefLowArg{$\Sigma$}
\let\oldDefLowArg\DefLowArg
\newsavebox{\myAbox}
\newsavebox{\myBbox}
\newcommand{\low}[2][\DefLowArg]{\savebox\myAbox{\vbox{#1}}\savebox\myBbox{\vbox{\ensuremath{#2}}}
\ifdim\dimexpr\ht\myAbox+\dp\myAbox<\dimexpr\ht\myBbox+\dp\myBbox\relax
\left({#2}\right)_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}
\else {#2}_{l_{\mathcal{A}}}\fi
}
\begin{document}

\[\low{\low{\Sigma}}\]

\[\low{\Sigma}\]
\[
\low{\sum_{i=3}^5 F(x)}
\]

\[
\low{\frac{F(x)}{x+5}}
\]

\[\low{F_x}\]

\[\low[1/4]{F(x)}\]

\[\low{x^2}\]

\[
\low{G_x}
\]

These commands may be should add without parentheses

\[
\low{g(z)}
\]
\[
\low{F(x)}
\]

{\bfseries Solution 1 Add an tall optional argument in the command like: \verb|\low[/]{F(x)}|}

\[
\low[/]{g(z)}
\]
\[
\low[/]{F(x)}
\]

{\bfseries Solution 2 Change the Default argument \verb|\DefLowArg| to something tall enough (return with \verb|\let\DefLowArg\oldDefLowArg|):}

\xdef\DefLowArg{/}

\[
\low{g(z)}
\]
\[
\low{F(x)}
\]
\let\DefLowArg\oldDefLowArg


{\bfseries And back to default}

\[
\low{F(X)}
\]

\end{document}
```

That produces:

[image]

PS:Of course manual solutions should be added in special cases but anyway in your command I am sure you would have exceptions for many cases.