# A macro that detects the subscript of the argument

Tags: macros, subscripts, superscripts

I'm not good at TeX programming. I've looked for the method that detects the subscript or superscript of the argument in macro. Existing relevant answers using the `xifthen` package ([Detecting subscript in command argument](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479110/142888)) are somewhat verbose for me to understand. Specifically, I want to make a macro such that if the argument has a subscript, `\dot{}` is applied only to the base character. It would have the form

```
\newcommand{\rdot}[1]{'code body'}
```

For example, `\rdot{a_{bcd}}` will give
[image]
instead of [image] that `\dot{a_{bcd}}` gives. `\rdot` should apply to superscripts in the same way.

Edit: I noticed that some macros in the answers yield a different result for boldface letters. For example, consider `\rdot{\bf{v}_{abc}}`. I didn't know it would make such a difference.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) So you want `\dot{a}_{bcd}` as result? Why not just use it like this?

Comment: are you sure you need a test, and not simply `\newcommand\rdot[1]{\dot #1}`  ?

Comment: @dexteritas I want to use `\dot` for macro characters. For example, I'd like to define `\text = v_{abc}` and apply `\dot` to `\text`.

Comment: I most certainly wouldn’t advice you to define a command called `\text`, as this command already exists and is pretty important!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing for `_` is fragile and likely to fail if the subscript is hidden in a macro or made with `\sb` rather than `_` or perhaps if it follows `^` so the base isn't "everything before `_`" .

I don't think it is needed as the accent will naturally apply to the first token or brace group.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\rdot[1]{\dot #1}

\begin{document}


$\rdot{a_{bcd}}$ and $\rdot{a}$ or even $\rdot{a^{2}_b}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But it gives a different result for a character inside another macro; for example, $ \bf{v}_{a} $. What would be a correction for that?

Comment: @Hermis14  well of course `\bf` should never be used in lates, and if you do use it (when it os defined,  which it is not defined by default) the syntax would be `{\bf a}` not `\bf{a}` then it would work with `\rdot` as would teh standard latex `\rdot{\mathbf{a}_{bcd}}`  in general you can use `{}` as in `\rdot{{abcdef}_{bcd}}`

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617514/1090

Comment: Wow, I didn't know there is a difference between `\bf{}` and `\mathbf{}`. It works great!

Comment: @Hermis14 `\bf` would make the rest of the expression be bold (or be undefined, it is not a standard latex command) compare `$\mathbf{a}bc$` and `$\bf{a}bc$`

Comment: I have a problem. When I define `\newcommand{\vect}{{\mathbf{v}}_{a}}` and apply `\rdot{\vect}`, the trick doesn't work.

Comment: @Hermis14 why questions should always have a full example....  If you add your `\vect` code to the example here you get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XAzsP.png) ie it works fine. I would guess you are using `amsmath` version of `\dot` which gives an error in that case, you could use `\newcommand\rdot[1]{\expandafter\dot #1}`

Comment: It works robustly. I really appreciate your persistent advice!

Answer (score 3):

This is a problem that has been bothering me, too. For instance, if you define a command `\abcd` that expands to `a_{bcd}`, then `\dot{\abcd}` expands to `\dot{a_{bcd}}` rather than `\dot{a}_{bcd}`. You can hack your way around this, but it’s never going to work robustly enough to cover all the cases you might run into. That was part of my motivation for developing the package `semantex` which allows things like this to work, but with a different syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{semantex}

\NewVariableClass\MyVar[
    output=\MyVar,
    define keys={
        {dot}{ command=\dot },
    },
]

\NewObject\MyVar\va{a}
\NewObject\MyVar\vb{b}
\NewObject\MyVar\vc{c}
\NewObject\MyVar\vd{d}
\NewObject\MyVar\vect{\mathbf{v}}[sep i=\va]

\begin{document}

\( \va[\vb\vc\vd, dot] \)

\( \va[\vb\vc\vd][dot] \)

\NewObject\MyVar\abcd[copy=\va,sep i=\vb\vc\vd]

\( \abcd[dot] \)

\( \vect[dot] \)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `\IfSubStr` (of package `xstring`) to check if the parameter contains `_` and then use `\StrBefore` and `\StrBehind`. This places the dot also centered over the variable, if it consists of multiple characters.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\rdot}[1]{%
    \IfSubStr{#1}{_}{%
        \StrBefore{#1}{_}[\@tempa]%
        \StrBehind{#1}{_}[\@tempb]%
        \dot{\@tempa}_{\@tempb}%
    }{%
        #1%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\rdot{a}, \rdot{a_{bcd}}, \rdot{asdf_{bcd}}$

\end{document}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: It seems your method is simple and practical. Would you give some comment on how to apply it to a boldface base character? Your method removes the base character for `\rdot{\bf{v}_{abc}}`.

Comment: I don't know a quick fix for this, but e.g. [egreg's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617510/123129) works for this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's more natural to type `\dot{a}_{x}`, but if you really want to, you can do it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\rdot}{m}
 {
  \hermis_check_subsup:nn { \dot } { #1 }
 }
% define analogously \rddot` and so on

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hermis_check_subsup:nn
 {
  \regex_match:nnTF { (\^|\_) } { #2 }
   {% there is a _ or ^ in the argument
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*?)(\^|\_)(.*) } { \c{dot}\cB\{\1\cE\}\2\3 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {% no _ or ^ in the argument
    #1{#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\rdot{a}+\rdot{a_{x}}+\rdot{a_{x_1}}+\rdot{a^2_x}+\rdot{a^2}+\rdot{a_x^2}$

$\rdot{\mathit{abc}_x}+\rdot{\mathit{ab}^2_x}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had to add: `\usepackage{xparse}`

Comment: @daxteritas Then you might want to update your TeX distribution. `:-)`

Comment: @Gaussler Ah, ok. Yes I have an older version on this machine.