# Is there a reason why I should not make use of commands such as \bf to bold my text instead of the "standard" ones?

Tags: bold

The question arose eversince I learnt about \textbf{} and I couldn't quite spot any differences against \bf.

Comment: Actually `\bf` is more akin to `\bfseries` than `\textbf`.  But there are good reasons to stick with the latter constructs, as many will point out.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Rookie question, How do you highlight (if that's the right word in this case) like you did the aforementioned commands?

Comment: `\bf` is not defined by default in latex and has not been since 1993, so unless you are using a _very_ old format it is best to stick to the standard commands.

Comment: @Lambert Use backticks `` to format code. By placing "\bf" between single backticks you will get `\bf`.

Comment: The answer to ["Correct" way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144) may also be worth having a look at.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\bf` has not been defined by default since LaTeX2e was introduced in 1993. Some classes may define it for compatibility with old documents but that can not be assumed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

this \textbf{that}

\end{document}
```

But

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}

this {\bf that}

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 this {\bf
              that}
?
```

Even when it is defined, the behaviour is not the same as `\textbf` as it ignores the current font settings:

Note that `that` is not italic here, but `\textbf` gives bold italic in an italic context.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\itshape


this {\bf that} \textbf{the other}

\end{document}
```