# Macro with braced output

Tags: macros, braces

I wrote a code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\tvm}[1]{{\mathbf{#1}}}

\newcommand{\tdot}[1]{\expandafter\dot#1}

\newcommand{\vecta}{{\tvm{v}}_{abc}^{def}}
\newcommand{\vectb}{\tvm{v}_{abc}^{def}}

\begin{document}
$ \tdot{\vecta} $ % line a
\\
$ \tdot{\vectb} $ % line b
\end{document}
```

where `\tdot` is used to apply `\dot` only to the base character of the argument that has subscripts, and 'line a' gives a correct result as

[image]

But 'line b' that uses `\vectb` gives an error. The difference comes from the braces around `\tvm{v}`. I would like to let the macro `\tvm` have its output braced somewhat internally so that I don't need to write braces for each use of `\tvm`.

Note that actual definition of `\tvm` that I use is

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\vm}[1]{
    \@tfor\next:=#1\do{
        \ifcat\next\relax
        {\boldsymbol{\next}}
        \else
        {\mathbf{\next}}
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
```

which discriminate between English and Greek.

Comment: Why don't you define a single command, which takes 3 parameters? If you need flexibility, you can also define one command per case.

Comment: as I sdaid before you ca use `{\tvm{v}}` to brace the base, but also use `\mathrm{def}` not `def` never use math italic for words, it is spaced to look like a product of variables. Also are you sure that `\ifcat` test does what you want (it seems very weird) and why use `\mathbf` (so getting upright bold) on some inputs but `\boldsymbol` (so getting bold italic) on others? why not simply use `\boldsymbol{#1}` or better, `\bm{#1}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, if you use a variant of the `\rdot` macro (that now mysteriously became `\tdot`) I suggested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617510/4427

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\tdot}{m}
 {
  \hermis_check_subsup:nn { \dot } { #1 }
 }
% define analogously \tddot and so on

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hermis_check_subsup:nn
 {
  \exp_args:Nne \regex_match:nnTF { (\^|\_) } { \text_expand:n { #2 } }
   {% there is a _ or ^ in the argument
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl { \text_expand:n { #2 } }
    \regex_replace_once:nnN { (.*?)(\^|\_)(.*) } { \c{dot}\cB\{\1\cE\}\2\3 } \l_tmpa_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {% no _ or ^ in the argument
    #1{#2}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\vm}[1]{%
  \@tfor\next:=#1\do{%
    \ifcat\next\relax
      \boldsymbol{\next}%
    \else
      \mathbf{\next}%
    \fi
  }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\vecta}{{\vm{v}}_{abc}^{def}}
\newcommand{\vectb}{\vm{v}_{abc}^{def}}


\begin{document}

$\tdot{a}+\tdot{a_{x}}+\tdot{a_{x_1}}+\tdot{a^2_x}+\tdot{a^2}+\tdot{a_x^2}$

$\tdot{\mathit{abc}_x}+\tdot{\mathit{ab}^2_x}$

$ \tdot{\vecta} $ % line a

$ \tdot{\vectb} $ % line b

\end{document}
```

There is too much indirection in your commands, so the simplistic approach of `\expandafter` cannot work.

[image]