# Vertical spacing of description environment of enumitem

Tags: environments, enumitem, box

I use an `description` environment defined in *enumitem*. First, my code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{descleft}{description}{1}
\setlist[descleft]{align=parleft, leftmargin=!, labelwidth=4cm, labelsep=1.5em, font=\normalfont\sffamily}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{descleftind}{%
    \vbox{%
        \global\widest=0pt%
        \def\item[##1]{%
            \settowidth\@tempdima{\textsf{\begin{array}[t]{@{}l@{}}##1\end{array}}}%
            % \settowidth\@tempdima{\textsf{##1}}%
            \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\relax
            \global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
        }%
        \setbox0=\vbox{\BODY}%
    }
    \begin{description}[
        align=parleft,
        labelsep=1.5em,
        leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+2em+0.05\columnwidth\relax,
        labelindent=0.05\columnwidth,
        labelwidth=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
%       topsep=0pt,
%       parsep=0pt,
        % partopsep=0pt,
        % itemsep=0pt,
        font=\normalfont\sffamily]
        \BODY
    \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test 1}

\begin{descleft}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleft}

\subsubsection{Test 2}

\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\subsubsection{Test 3}
Test line
\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\end{document}
```

`descleft` environment is defined by using the macro provided by *enumitem*, whereas `descleftind` is defined in `\NewEnviron` macro of the *environ* package. As both of the definitions do not have any vertical spacing option in the `description` environment, I guessed that the results would have no difference at least in vertical spacing. The section `Test 1` contains the result of `descleft` while `Test 2` and `Test 3` have the results of `descleftind`. What is weird at this point is that `Test 2` has unintended vertical spacing between the section text and the list. However, a text between these does not influence the spacing as shown in `Test 3`. What's happening in this code and what should I do to remove the spacing? I guess the `\vbox` macro has the key.

[image]

Edit: I am currently using a makeshift that assigns a manual spacing using `\vspace`:

```
\NewEnviron{descrightind}[1][0pt]{%
    \vspace{#1}
    \vbox{
        \global\widest=0pt%
        \def\item[##1]{%
            \settowidth\@tempdima{\textsf{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}##1\end{tabular}}}%
            \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\relax
            \global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
        }%
        \setbox0=\vbox{\BODY}%
    }
    \begin{description}[
        align=parright,
        labelsep=1.5em,
        leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+2em+0.05\columnwidth\relax,
        labelindent=0.05\columnwidth,
        labelwidth=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
        font=\normalfont\sffamily]
        \BODY
    \end{description}%
}
```

For example,

```
\subsubsection{Test 3}
Test line
\begin{descleftind}[-2em]
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are typesetting a `\vbox`. Don't.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{descleft}{description}{1}
\setlist[descleft]{
  align=parleft,
  leftmargin=!,
  labelwidth=4cm,
  labelsep=1.5em,
  font=\normalfont\sffamily
}

\newlength\widest
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{descleftind}{%
    \setbox0=\vbox{%
        \global\widest=0pt%
        \def\item[##1]{%
            \settowidth\@tempdima{\textsf{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}##1\end{tabular}}}%
            % \settowidth\@tempdima{\textsf{##1}}%
            \ifdim\@tempdima>\widest\relax
            \global\widest=\@tempdima\fi%
        }%
        \BODY
    }
    \begin{description}[
        align=parleft,
        labelsep=1.5em,
        leftmargin=\dimexpr\widest+2em+0.05\columnwidth\relax,
        labelindent=0.05\columnwidth,
        labelwidth=\dimexpr\widest+0.5em\relax,
%       topsep=0pt,
%       parsep=0pt,
        % partopsep=0pt,
        % itemsep=0pt,
        font=\normalfont\sffamily]
        \BODY
    \end{description}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test 1}

\begin{descleft}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleft}

\subsubsection{Test 2}

\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really \\ long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\subsubsection{Test 3}
Test line
\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A version that avoids typesetting the body in the disposable `\vbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{descleft}{description}{1}
\setlist[descleft]{
  align=parleft,
  leftmargin=!,
  labelwidth=4cm,
  labelsep=1.5em,
  font=\normalfont\sffamily
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{descleftind}{O{}+b}
 {
  \hermis_descleftind:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
 {}

\dim_new:N \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim
\seq_new:N \l__hermis_descleftind_items_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \hermis_descleftind:nn
 {
  % let's measure the labels
  \dim_zero:N \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__hermis_descleftind_items_seq { \item } { #2 }
  % the first item would be empty
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l__hermis_descleftind_items_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  % measure the widest label
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__hermis_descleftind_items_seq \__hermis_descleftind_measure:n
  % now typeset
  \begin{description}[
        align=parleft,
        labelsep=1.5em,
        leftmargin=\dim_eval:n { \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim+2em+0.05\columnwidth },
        labelindent=0.05\columnwidth,
        labelwidth=\dim_eval:n { \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim+0.5em },
%       topsep=0pt,
%       parsep=0pt,
        % partopsep=0pt,
        % itemsep=0pt,
        font=\normalfont\sffamily,
        #1 % you may want to override some parameters
  ]
  #2
    \end{description}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__hermis_descleftind_measure:n
 {
  \__hermis_descleftind_measure:w #1 \q_stop
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__hermis_descleftind_measure:w [ #1 ] #2 \q_stop
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \sffamily \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular} }
  \dim_set:Nn \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim
   {
    \dim_max:nn { \l__hermis_descleftind_label_dim } { \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\subsubsection{Test 1}

\begin{descleft}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleft}

\subsubsection{Test 2}

\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really \\ long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\subsubsection{Test 3}
Test line
\begin{descleftind}
\item[Short] \lipsum[1-7][1-2]
\item[A really really long label] \lipsum[1-7][3-4]
\end{descleftind}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) The code is originated from [Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/130099/142888). I've been using it with some minor retouch not knowing the principle in it. But I am not really familiar with the syntax of your original code. Is it standard syntax supported by LaTeX? Would you recommend some material needed to follow your answer?

Comment: In fact, you've answered my question before with the syntax [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/617510/142888). But it didn't work with multiple errors on *overleaf*. That's why I didn't select your answer. Surprisingly, I noticed that it works really well in my *TeXstudio*. I don't know why there's a difference between overleaf and TeXstudio.

Comment: Your original approach seems much better in that it allows *Go-to-source* functionality that TeXstudio provides because it does not involve *environ* package, whereas my code doesn't.